# date checking in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In design i have 2 textboxes, 2 imagebuttons and 1 calendar for both imagebuttons click event
In page load i am displaying todays date in both textboxes
Page_load looks like this;

```
txtfrdate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Today()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
txttodate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Today()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

now i am changing only the  value of txttodate(todate is greater than from date) and then click button message should showing "From Date should be greater than to date"
I written the imagebutton1 and 2 click event as follows

```
Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click
  Calendar1.Visible = True
  Calendar1.SelectedDates.Clear()
  Session("click") = 1
End Sub

Protected Sub ImageButton2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton2.Click
    Calendar1.Visible = True
    Calendar1.SelectedDates.Clear()
    Session("click") = 2
End Sub
```

and in calendar selectionchanged event

```
Protected Sub Calendar1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Calendar1.SelectionChanged
    Select Case (Session("click"))
        Case 1 : txtfrdate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            Session("fd") = Calendar1.SelectedDate
        Case 2 : txttodate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            Session("td") = Calendar1.SelectedDate
    End Select
    Calendar1.Visible = False

    Label4.Visible = False
End Sub
```

and i am checking date after clicking the view click button as follows

```
If txtfrdate.Text = "" Then
    Label4.Visible = True
    Label4.Text = "Select From Date"
ElseIf txttodate.Text = "" Then
    Label4.Visible = True
    Label4.Text = "Select To Date"
ElseIf txtfrdate.Text > txttodate.Text Then
    Label4.Visible = True
    Label4.Text = "From Date Must be Smaller than To Date"
```

actually my problem is when i only change the txttodate and todate is greater than from date but still the message showing From date should be greater than to date"
my output is showing

```
From Date: 31/08/2012  - i am not changing current date during page load
To Date: 29/09/2012 - changing by selecting the calendar message is showing
```

From Date Must be Smaller than To Date

Please hjelp me
thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not quite sure if I completely understood your question. And I don't think it is intended to compare two strings? `txtfrdate.Text > txttodate.text` compares the string values and **does not compare dateTime objects**!

Use this example and adapt it to your requirements to check dateTime values.

```
    DateTime dtFrom = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime dtTo = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(5, 0,0,0));

    if (dtFrom > dtTo)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Invalid To-Date");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OK");
    }
```